# Remove characters before character "\"

Tags: c#

How effectively remove all character in string that placed before character "\"?

**Input:** C:\Users\vadym\OneDrive\Робочий стіл\sharp-kn3-lab2-2022-autoteam\AutoOA\AutoOA.UI\wwwroot\Images\room.png

**Output:** \Images\room.png

Comment: Why `\Images\room.png` and not, say, `\wwwroot\Images\room.png`? How do you decide that this ``\`` is better than that ``\``?

Comment: so it seems you want the last directory and the filename. But this is merely a guess. When handling strings that contain a path it is usefull to have a look at the documentation of the classes [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-7.0) and [Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-7.0). They contain a lot of helpful methods to extract information from a path

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this without having to perform manual manipulation of the path is by relying on `Directory` and `Path` classes.

Note that this doesn't include some error conditions and corner cases that you might want to double check for:

```
var input = @"C:\Users\vadym\OneDrive\Робочий стіл\sharp-kn3-lab2-2022-autoteam\AutoOA\AutoOA.UI\wwwroot\Images\room.png";
var parentDirectory = Directory.GetParent(input).Parent.FullName;
var relativePath = Path.GetRelativePath(parentDirectory, input);

Console.WriteLine($"Input: {input}");
Console.WriteLine($"Directory: {parentDirectory}");
Console.WriteLine($"Relative path: {relativePath}");
```